# Conditional markup type and formatting in rdlc-Report

Tags: rdlc

I have a problem with formatting in one of my rdlc-reports. I'm using an ObjectDatasource with a property of type object called Value and some boolean fields like IsValueDate, IsValueInt and IsValueDouble. The value at runtime can be anything from a HTML string to a date object or an integer or double.

I want to use the report for an Ecxel-export of some data. The formatting string for the report field is something like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!IsValueDouble.Value, "#,##0.0########", 
 IIf(Fields!IsValueInt.Value, "#,##0",
 IIf(Fields!IsValueDate.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", "")
))
```

This works, but an HTML string is shown as plain text with all tags. My idea was to set the MarkupType with this expression:

```
=IIf(Not(Fields!IsValueDouble.Value) And
 Not(Fields!IsValueInt.Value) And
 Not(Fields!IsValueDate.Value), "HTML", "None")
```

This renders the HTML tags as expected but the conditional formatting of dates and numbers is ignored.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To render HTML in RDLC report, you need to create placeholder in the cell or textBox and set MarkupType property of the placeholder as "HTML".

Here is related documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx